# No Page Rank after switching domains

Tags: seo, page, pagerank

Our website hasn't had a Page Rank since it started a year ago.  It has been 0 ever since we changed the to domain to http://www.accessiblehomehealthcare.com from www.accessiblehhc.com so that we could put some keywords in.  We had a page rank of 1 at least.  I know that it can be a variety of things but we had a page rank before and would like to get it back and even higher.  Our site is Wordpress 2.7.

Any hints or suggestions, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons is likely to be that your old domain uses a 302 (temporary) redirect to the new one. [This should be a 301 (permanent) redirect](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633).

The other reasons would be around where your back-links are coming from (and to), since PR is a measurement of backlinks...

Comment: Hi Mike, That is a good answer.  How did you know that the old domain used a 302 redirect?

Comment: You can see the HTTP response with a tool like REDbot: http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.accessiblehhc.com

Comment: I used [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/), you could try [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), or REDbot as @Ciaran mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mike Hudson's answer. If you transfer the domain, the pr of old domain will not be with that. Now, you need to do further process to get PR like seo and internet marketing as Backlinks are for your older domain. So you need to try to increase more backlinks for the new domain.

Comment: Thanks Mike and Kunjal,  I really need to get a page rank for my company website.  I know that page rank isn't every thing but that is very important to my superiors here.  Now, what's the best software or company to hire for the backlinks.

Comment: @kdorival I don't believe in software for backlinks - the best recipe is to have something **worthy** of linking to. That being said, it's a dog-eat-dog world out there. Try related directories, associated companies, suppliers, testimonials etc...

Answer (score 0):

> I know that it can be a variety of things but we had a page rank before and would like to get it back and even higher.

It can't be a variety of things. There's only one factor that matters to PageRank: links. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank for an explanation.

> Our site is Wordpress 2.7.

You need to upgrade urgently to the latest version of WordPress (right now we're on 3.1.1). Staying on 2.7 is ***not*** a good idea.

> Now, what's the best software or company to hire for the backlinks.

Don't do this. The best way to get links is by having content that people find worthy of sharing. Continue to improve the content on your site and make it easy for people to share that content in lots of different ways. Be active on facebook, twitter and other online communities. Ask for links from the sites of your associates or partners.

Comment: +1 for upgrading WordPress versions - there are *SO* many security fixes since 2.7.